# DiffUtil.Callback() not working as the same as notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a message list that contains messages. And I used a regular `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead of `ListAdapter`.

**ChatFragment**

```
chatViewModel.msgListDisplayLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    chatAdapter.setChat(it)
})
```

Here is the function to update `messageList` in adapter.

**ChatAdapter**

```
fun setChat(newMessages: List<Message>) {
    val diffUtil = ChatDiffUtil(messageList, newMessages)
    val diffResults = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffUtil)

    messageList = newMessages
    diffResults.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)

    --> Method of using notifyDataSetChanged()
    // messageList = newMessages
    // notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Previously I am using `notifyDataSetChanged()` and the list item can be updated instantly, but without any animation.
Thus, I decided to use `DiffUtils()` and I got the nice animation when my list's item got append/remove.

However, when I want to update one of the item, `DiffUtils` seems do not have any visible effect.

Using **notifyDataSetChanged()** - can instantly update the row.
[image]

Using **DiffUtils()** - cannot update instantly.
[image]

What had I done wrongly? Please advise me.